# Problem: horizontal scrollbar for flex datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex4, scrollbar

I have 10 columns in datgrid so i want datagrid to be horizontally scrollable.
Im getting vertical scrollbar(auto generated without specifying vertical scroll policy on) for mxDatagrid but Im not getting horizontal scrollbar.
how to solve this?
Im using flex 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please make the horizontalScrollPolicy="on" then it will display the scroll

and i also refer this link

this might be helpful to u

[Faster Horizantal scroll](http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2008/11/faster_datagrid_horizontal_scr.html)

Comment: but without using verticalScrollPolicy="on" vertical scrollbar coming.. Anyway i can use horizontalScrollPolicy="on".. but by default why it is not coming?

Comment: if horizontalScrollPolicy="on" then if we use 1 column then also it is visible but not enabled. if columns exceed the datagrid's width then scrollbar enabled

Comment: how about put it on value auto? HScrollBar will be visible if columns does not fit in the given space.

Comment: @san_flexy In default horizantal scrollbar is off when u make it on then it draws the horizantal Scrollbar internally and make it disabled. Thats what happening. If u want not to be disabled,  extend the component and make the 'scroll policy "on" & visible= "false"' and override the updatedisplaylist check the condition and make the scroll bar visible at particular time.

Comment: @Sudharsanan Thank you for information.. but its not flexible as vertical scrollbars which appears automatically if rows does not fit in the given space. :)

Comment: After a  long time I'm accepting this as a correct answer.. I used  `horizontalScrollPolicy="auto"` but I was expecting this should be a default behavior of datagrid.